# prove $\inf \frac{1}{1+n}$ is zero

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

${a_n}={\frac{1}{1+n}}$ for all natural numbers.

how to prove $inf(a_n)=0$
I need help with the part that I  have to apply the archimedian axiom.
should I say there exists an N such that $\frac{1}{1+N}<0+\epsilon$
should I begin with $N>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ then how to develop that.
I need a clean proof for this part please. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the archimedean axiom at all? Just show that $a_n>0$ for all $n$ and that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $a_n<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. From $N>\frac1\varepsilon$, you deduce that $1+N>\frac1\varepsilon$ and that therefore $\frac1{1+N}<\varepsilon$. So, no $\varepsilon>0$ is a lower bound of your set. It follows that $0$ is the greatest lower bound.